# How to copy image from Azure storage account to ARM storage account using Java?

Tags: java, storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-resource-manager, azcopy

I want to copy my existing custom image from Azure classic storage account to Azure ARM storage account by using Java.
(Implementation of **azCopy** using Java programming)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to implement the `azCopy` cmdlet below using Java programming.

> **Blob: [Copy single blob across Storage accounts](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-use-azcopy/#blob-copy)**
>
> AzCopy /Source:https://sourceaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer1 /Dest:https://destaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer2 /SourceKey:key1 /DestKey:key2 /Pattern:abc.txt

As reference, here is my code sample for implementing the above cmdlet using Java programming which depend on [Azure Storage Client SDK for Java](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/azure-storage/4.4.0).

The key method for copying is [`CloudBlob.startCopy`](http://azure.github.io/azure-storage-java/com/microsoft/azure/storage/blob/CloudBlob.html#startCopy(java.net.URI)).

```
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageCredentials;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageUri;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlob;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlockBlob;

public class AzCopySample {

    private static final String STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING_TEMPLATE = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=%s;AccountKey=%s;";

    public static CloudBlob genBlobReference(Map<String, String> cmdOptions, String option) throws URISyntaxException, InvalidKeyException, StorageException {
        URI uri = new URI(cmdOptions.get(option));
        String host = uri.getHost();
        String account = host.substring(0, host.indexOf("."));
        String key = cmdOptions.get(option+"Key");
        String connectionString = String.format(STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING_TEMPLATE, account, key);
        StorageCredentials credentials = StorageCredentials.tryParseCredentials(connectionString);
        StorageUri storageUri = new StorageUri(uri);
        CloudBlob blob = new CloudBlockBlob(storageUri, credentials);
        return blob;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, InvalidKeyException, StorageException {
        String command = "AzCopy /Source:https://sourceaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer1 /Dest:https://destaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer2 /SourceKey:key1 /DestKey:key2 /Pattern:abc.txt";
        String[] cmdItems = command.split(" ");
        Map<String, String> cmdOptions = new HashMap<>();
        for(int i = 1; i < cmdItems.length; i++) {
            String cmdItem = cmdItems[i];
            int index = cmdItem.indexOf(":");
            String key = cmdItem.substring(0, index);
            String value = cmdItem.substring(index+1);
            cmdOptions.put(key, value);
        }
        CloudBlob source = genBlobReference(cmdOptions, "/Source");
        CloudBlob dest = genBlobReference(cmdOptions, "/Dest");
        dest.startCopy(source.getUri());
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Peter, Thank you very much for the help. But i am struggling the error "Exception in thread "main" com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature." Can you help me ?

Comment: Else give me code to Copy image from classic storage to ARM storage....